# Disable access to category page

Tags: wordpress, url, url-rewriting, seo

On my Wordpress website I have a URL structure:

```
website.com/cars/black/porsche
website.com/cars/yellow/fiat
website.com/cars/about
```

To do that, I've created empty category named 'cars' and empty blank page 'cars'.

Nextly I've created categories black and yellow which parent is car and properly posts: porsche and fiat.

How is the better solution to disable access to pages: website.com/cars/, website.com/cars/yellow?

A: Use 301 to redirect to 404 page?
B: Use 301 to redirect to another post in category?
C: How to prevent website from Google Search Engine to not index unwanted URL's? NoIndex+NoFollow+Disable showing in sitemaps are enough?

Answer (score 0):

You can install SEO plugin by Yoast for noindex and nofollow. I think that's the easiest way. If these pages were already indexed by Google remove a page using Webmaster tools.

For no access - why do you need these pages? If you have noindex and nofollow these pages won't show up in Google search and if you don't have any links to these pages accessible to users nobody will know about them.